# finding all column_names that have data_type LONG VARCHAR in Oracle

Tags: oracle, varchar

I crafted the following PLSQL-statement and pass it to SqlPlus in Oracle (11g)
as normal user, to find out which column names in all_user_tables (I'm actually only interested on those tables that are created by the schema owner) are of type LONG VARCHAR

```
select table_name, column_name from all_tab_columns where data_type='LONG VARCHAR';
```

The result is 
no rows selected

but I'm sure that I have made use of LONG VARCHAR in a couple of places in tables. Somehow I'm using the wrong table to search or some other logic is wrong.

Comment: There isn't such a datatype as `LONG VARCHAR` in Oracle. Did you mean `LONG`, or `CLOB` or maybe even just `VARCHAR2`? ETA: Hmm a quick google seems to indicate that `LONG VARCHAR` is a synonym for `LONG`. Try searching for that instead. On a separate note, `LONG` is a deprecated datatype; I'm hoping that you're wanting to convert them to `CLOB`s?

Comment: If you do `create table t(col long varchar)`, you will create a table t with field col as `long` datatype.

Comment: So the VARCHAR is just tolerated syntactically but doesn't reflect in the storage type, right? So would I have to search for data_tape LONG instead?

Comment: @Krischu - yes just search for `LONG`, [but the data is slightly different](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10646/oci03typ.htm#LNOCI16294), apparently.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select table_name, column_name, data_type 
from all_tab_columns 
where data_type IN('LONG','VARCHAR2');
```

Or this

```
SELECT * 
FROM DBA_TAB_COLUMNS
where data_type IN('LONG','VARCHAR2')
and owner in 'YOUR_SCHEMA';
```

Comment: How would I confine this request to the schemaowner's tables?

Comment: You only need `data_type = 'LONG'` to answer the question though (but the extra space before `VARCHAR2` means that won't match anything anyway). And the second query should have `=`, not `in`. If you don't have access to DBA_TAB_COLUMNS look in ALL_TAB_COLUMNS instead.

Comment: corrected the typo, when it's not clear what the user is asking I err on the side of caution

Comment: I have to correct myself: Indeed there is no data_type LONG VARCHAR in Oracle. I messed up. It should have been VARCHAR2 I had to search for. But the solutions still apply. Thanks a lot.